# Query Distinct values from a multi-valued column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to query all the unique values in my "Tags" column.
Each row within the tags column can consist of multiple values.
So without being forced to go into normalization, how can I query a multi-valued column?

Example Rows:

```
Networking
Professionalism
Time Management
Communication, Networking
Career Management, Professionalism
Networking
Communication
Attitude, Interpersonal Skills, Professionalism
Business Protocol, Career Management, Communication, Leadership
Business Protocol, Networking
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I'm programming a blog page in coldfusion, grabbing from a microsoft access database.

Comment: If you are using Access, then fix the data structure.  The string manipulations are painful.

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't be forced to that. I read examples, but I have been unable to even read the statements due to the shear complexity of the queries. I was hoping they were bad examples, but what you said matches up quite well with what I have seen. Thanks for possibly saving me a couple hours of searching readable examples...

Comment: You might also consider to another database.  Almost anything is better.

Comment: Amen to that, but I'm forced to use this database for a client along with coldfusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the maximum number of elements is predictable you can use this (please note that you need to use `UNION`, not `UNION ALL`)

```
Select DISTINCT thefield from thetable where Instr(thefield, ',') = 0
UNION 
Select Distinct Mid(thefield, 1, Instr(thefield, ',')) from thetable Where len(thefield) - len(replace(thefield,',','')) = 1
UNION 
Select Distinct Mid(thefield, Instr(thefield, ',')+1) from thetable Where len(thefield) - len(replace(thefield,',','')) = 1
UNION 
Select Distinct Mid(thefield, Instr(thefield, ',')+1, Instr(Instr(thefield, ',')+1,thefield, ',')) from thetable Where len(thefield) - len(replace(thefield,',','')) = 2
UNION 
Select Distinct Mid(thefield, Instr(Instr(thefield, ',')+1,thefield, ',')+1) from thetable Where len(thefield) - len(replace(thefield,',','')) = 2
--.. and so on (repeat last two Selects as many time as you wish, increasing the where condition by one for each pair)
```

Looks a bit clunky, but should do the job. Untested, so, you may have a stray comma appearing before or after a value